# Linq2Xml ограничение на загрузку из XML файла

Tags: c#, linq, linq2xml

Здравствуйте есть большой XML файл, более 500000 записей, из него часто приходится дергать корректировочную информацию. чтобы не грузить файл полностью а с помощью linq выполнить фильтрацию записей.

```
<root>
 <esrs>
   <rc int_ESR="-1594" str_Name="ПОБОЖИЙ"/>
   <rc int_ESR="-1593" str_Name="ФЕДОСЕЕВ"/>
   <rc int_ESR="-1592" str_Name="ГЛУХАРИНЫЙ"/>
 </esrs>
```

код загрузки всех станций:

```
  public IEnumerable<Station> SetResponse(XDocument xmlDoc, IEnumerable<Station> stationValid)
    {

            var listStationsNameQuery =
            from train in xmlDoc.Descendants("rc")
            select new
            {
                Esr = (string)train.Attribute("int_ESR"),
                Name = (string)train.Attribute("str_Name"),
            };
    }
```

А мне нужно грузить только станции указанные в stationValid по равенству ESR кода? Подскажите как сделать такое ограничение на Linq запрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С `XDocument` не выйдет не грузить весь документ в память. Если вам нужно только читать информацию, нужно использовать `XmlReader`, он потоковый.

Например, чтобы найти все `str_Name`, соответствующие данному `int_ESR`, подойдёт вот такой код:

```
var goodEsrValues = new HashSet<string>(
    stationValid.Select(station => station.ESR.ToString()));
using (TextReader tr = ...)
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(tr))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element || reader.Name != "rc")
            continue;
        var attr = reader.GetAttribute("int_ESR");
        if (!goodEsrValues.Contains(attr))
            continue;
        var name = reader.GetAttribute("str_Name");
        if (name != null)
            yield return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Т.е. Linq уже работает на строчках документа в памяти? А с  XmlReader примерно как будет?

Comment: @Aldmi: XmlReader не грузит документ в память, а читает и выдаёт по кусочкам. Сейчас напишу пример.

Comment: @Aldmi: А `XDocument`, да, грузит в память всё :-\

Answer (score 0):

Если бы надо было найти по одному ключу, можно было бы XPath использовать, в вашем случае может подойдёт такой вариант:

```
public IEnumerable<Station> SetResponse(XDocument xmlDoc, IEnumerable<Station> stationValid)
{
        var validEsr = new HashSet<string>(stationValid.Select(s => s.Esr));
        foreach(var elem in xmlDoc.Descendants("rc"))
        {
            var esr = (string)train.Attribute("int_ESR");
            if (validEsr.Contain(esr))
            {
                yield return new
                {
                    Esr = esr,
                    Name = (string)train.Attribute("str_Name"),
                };
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: А если использовать еще одну переменную from.                    var listStationsNameQuery =
                from train in xmlDoc.Descendants("rc")
                from station in stationValid          
                where (string)train.Attribute("int_ESR") == station.EcpCode.ToString() && !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)train.Attribute("str_Name"))
                select new
                {
                    Esr = (string)train.Attribute("int_ESR"),
                    Name = (string)train.Attribute("str_Name"),
                };